# Preventing horizontal scrolling on mobile (HTML/CSS/JS)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I'm putting the finishing touches on [this parallax website](http://jewelry-site.appspot.com/) but I'm having trouble preventing some very unattractive horizontal scrolling effects (try it yourself on a touch device by dragging directly to the left).

I've adapted the parallax technique described [here](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/) using 3D CSS transforms. Unfortunately, one of the side-effects seems to be that **the browser thinks the images are wider than the viewport, even though they aren't**. I've already tried:

- Adding `overflow-x: hidden;` to the parallax images' containing div, and while that's hidden the horizontal scrollbar, it alone does not actually prevent horizontal scrolling.
- Adding a partial workaround `scroll` event listener to reset the `scrollLeft` of the container back to 0 with each scroll, which solves the problem entirely on desktop (AFAICT) and partly on mobile (at least when scrolling diagonally).

Unfortunately, it seems that, at least on Android (I don't have an iPhone to test) it's still possible to scroll horizontally without triggering the `scroll` event workaround. Even more mystifying, while it's in this weird horizontally-scrolled mode I've programmatically traversed the entire DOM and not a single element has a `scrollLeft` property `!= 0`. I've also called `$('*').scrollLeft(0);` from the console and it doesn't reset the scrolling. Now calling `.preventDefault()` on all `touchmove` events *does* prevent the horizontal scrolling, but it also effectively breaks the site as a whole since it prevents vertical scrolling too--so that's a no-go.

**So how is this thing scrolling horizontally if nothing has a `scrollLeft` other than `0`, and how can I prevent/workaround this scrolling behavior?**